# Java String newline/indentation matching

Tags: java, string, indentation, matching

I have this sample String(With the newlines/indentations, marked as ""):
The number of crypto currency, fruits and direction entries may vary but the format/syntax stays the same.

Note:
I have not figured out how to add space/indentation in the question so if anyone knows how to do it, please send me the instructions. Thanks!

```
bitcoin litecoin 11  
exit  
bitcoin litecoin 16  
""ripple 77  
""exit    
exit    
**apple banana 55  
exit  
apple banana 55/2  
""coconut 1  
""exit  
""dragonfruit 2  
""exit    
exit**       
north west 11  
exit    
south west 7  
""north 12  
""exit    
exit
```

The goal is to filter out all fruit related text and their corresponding exit(marked in bold).

I plan to do a String replace replacing the fruit substring with nothing "". 
The start index can be found with indexOf("apple banana"), but the endIndex is a bit trickier since we have multiple "exit" after the last "apple banana".

The exit we are after are the first non-indented exit after the last "apple banana" entry. The last "apple banana" entry can be found with lastIndexOf("apple banana") but how do we match the first non-indented exit from the last "apple banana"?

Any solutions that works is most welcome! Thanks!

Comment: So you want to remove all instances of: line starting with `apple banana` and ending with `[newline] + exit`?

Comment: *I have not figured out how to add space/indentation in the question*: paste your well-formatted code. Then select it and hit Ctrl-K (or click the "code" icon of the editor).

Comment: @Mena Yes, removing all instances starting with apple banana and the last [newline] + exit which "belongs" to the last apple banana entry

Comment: @JB Nizet Awesome, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to replace text in your input that:

- starts with `apple banana`, and
- ends with `[newline]exit`
- with anything in between the two terms
- where nested `exit` statements have the peculiarity of being indented (i.e. by `""`)

... you could use the following regex-based solution:

```
// original text
String text = "bitcoin litecoin 11\nexit\nbitcoin litecoin 16\n\"\"ripple 77\n\"\"exit\nexit\napple banana 55\nexit"
    + "\napple banana 55/2\n\"\"coconut 1\n\"\"exit\n\"\"dragonfruit 2\n\"\"exit\nexit\nnorth west 11\nexit"
    + "\nsouth west 7\n\"\"north 12\n\"\"exit\nexit";
//                           | starting with fruit
//                           |            | anything in the middle
//                           |            |  | ends with newline + exit, then
//                           |            |  |     | newline or end of input
//                           |            |  |     |        | dot also represents 
//                           |            |  |     |        | newlines
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("apple banana.*?\nexit(\n|$)", Pattern.DOTALL);
StringBuffer replacement = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
// iteratively replacing with empty
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(replacement, "");
}
// appending tail text after last find
m.appendTail(replacement);
System.out.println(replacement);
```

**Output**

```
bitcoin litecoin 11
exit
bitcoin litecoin 16
""ripple 77
""exit
exit
north west 11
exit
south west 7
""north 12
""exit
exit
```